# Typescript: import { groupBy } from 'lodash' ReferenceError: require is not defined

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, lodash, require

I'm trying to use groupBy from lodash in a .ts file like this:

```
import { groupBy } from 'lodash';
```

But after `tsc .\index.ts -w` the resulting index.js turns that import into `var lodash_1 = require("lodash");` and the following error appears:

```
index.js:28 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "final_exercise",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "require": "^0.4.4",
    "typescript-require": "^0.3.0"
  }
```

The error happens with and without require and typescript-require being installed. Installing
require needed the `npm audit fix --force`, not sure if that's normal or not.

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2019",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["ES2019", "dom", "dom.iterable"],
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
  }
}
```

I also have this on the end of index.html, else the error would be `ReferenceError: exports is not defined`:

```
<script> var exports = {}; </script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

Since I'm new to Typescript, to modules and everything associated, I must be doing something wrong or I'm missing something. I've checked all similar questions with answers but nothing so far has worked.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `"module": "commonjs",` in the `tsconfig.json` means that the TypeScript code is transpiled to CommonJs modules. You can't use CommonJs  modules in a broswer without module loaders. You can either use a bundler like Webpack that bundles all files to one large file, a module loader like SystemJS or you can use ES6 modules with an Internet URL like `import { groupBy } from 'https://deno.land/x/lodash@4.17.15-es/lodash.js';`

Comment: @jabba I see. I tried that, but: index.ts:17:25 - `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'https://deno.land/x/lodash@4.17.15-es/lodash.js' or its corresponding type declarations.`

Comment: I guess the last approach in combination with TypeScript is the most complex one, because you have to separately install and configure type declarations. I recommend Webpack or another bundler (Rollup, Parcel). That's probably the most common way. Or you drop TypeScript and use ES6 modules.